# How to get ready for an internet connection error, when I am running an automatic script?

Tags: python, exception, web-scraping, runtime-error

I wrote a code in Python 2.7, which one I am web-scraping a lot of table from ~1000 websites and repeat it with a particular interval (with an infinity loop). But, if there are some problem with the Internet connection, and the webpage can't loading in, nothing is happening.
No error message, the script is running, but "stop" at this webpages, and that's all. How can I avoid this emerging problem?

Here my code detail:

```
import
.
.
.

def scrape(urls) #here I am web-scraping
.
.
def get_data(): #here I am enumareting the all website + convert it in the right format
.
.
connection = MYSQLdb #here I am sending these dataes to the mysql table
.
.
while True: #here I am defining the infinity loop and the period
MY_INFINITY LOOP:
while True:
get_data()
get_data2()
dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=4)
while datetime.now() < dt:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Where and what I have to write, to avoid this problem?

UPDATE:

```
def inf_loop():
    while True:
        get_data()
        get_data2()
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=4)
        while datetime.now() < dt:
            time.sleep(1)

while True:
    p = Process(target=inf_loop, args=(your_code_args,))
    p.start()
    p.join(seconds=180) # will try to join process p for timeout
    if p.is_alive():
        # too long, terminate process
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate process with `multiprocessing` library.
Your loop will look something like that:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def your_code():
    # something

while True:
    p = Process(target=your_code, args=(your_code_args,))
    p.start()
    p.join(your_timeout) # will try to join process p for timeout
    if p.is_alive():
        # too long, terminate process
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

To get data from `multiprocessing.Process` use `multiprocessing.Queue`. Actually, you can use a queue to monitor process state more flexible than timeout.

As an additional benefit, you can easily parallel your scraping with `multiprocessing` library, if your architecture allows it. `multiprocessing.Pool` might be helpful

Comment: I have to write it in the end? or before the infinity loop? and what is this "your_code"?

Comment: @tardos93 That is your infinity loop. `your_code` is a function you want to monitor, so that should be your code that makes scraping.

Comment: I updated my question, with my loop, and the way what you suggested for me. Is this correct?

Comment: @tardos93 the function you pass to `Process` never stops, so I suggest you remove infinite_loop from there -- you need only one such loop. or I misunderstand your intention. Probably if you tell what your goals are in a bit more detail I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: my goal : webscraping->convert into the right format->upload into a mysqldb (and do it again every 4 hours, like my infinity function do). The logical goal is that in my opinion, if there isn't an internetconnection and this script stop on a website, write output a little text like "internet connection problem" or something else, whereof i know there is something wrong.